# Ionic NativeGeocoder plugin not working with Angular Forms and Capacitor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ionic-framework, web

I'm doing a simple Ionic form app and I've been having trouble when trying to use the [NativeGeocoder Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-geocoder) when I add the (private nativeGeocoder: NativeGeocoder) declaration in the constructor that page does not load anymore and without any errors. I haven't found anything to fix that error maybe somebody has encountered it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to register it within your component.module.ts file as a provider.

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [
     Geolocation
   ]
})
```

Comment: For me, it's not working. Can you pass me the import?

Comment: No i cannot. it's not hard to do...

Comment: For me, it happens the same it continues not to open the page. Even with that added to the app component module.